# Irradiance and current

Tags: optics

Is there a relationship between Ir-radiance of an LED and the forward current supplied to it? I am designing a photo-therapy device for neonatal jaundice treatment. The required quantity is Ir-radiance. However, I'm unable to measure it in our college because of non-availability of a radiometer. So I was wondering if there is a relationship between these two. Then I can supply the required current to the LED to get the desired irradiance.

Comment: You probably speak about the flux emitted by a LED diode (or a light intensity). (Ir- can lead someone to think about Infra-Red part, which may be a different question). I would suggest to clarify the terms.

Comment: You will need radiometer to get any approval/trial ... especially neonatal. There are too many variables ... and many vendors sell LEDs of different electrical and optical performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect they are proportional, but I haven't checked. If each electron creates a photon, the number of photons per second is proportional to the number of electrons per second.

Irradiance is flux of radiant energy per unit surface area normal to the energy flow. Neither area of the diode nor angle of emmission changes.